# Do let and const count as making declaration statements?

Tags: javascript

Reading this [article](https://medium.com/launch-school/javascript-expressions-and-statements-4d32ac9c0e74) about declaration statements, it says `var x` and function declarations are examples of 'declaration statements'. What about `let x` or `const x`?

Comment: They are also declaration statements.  You are declaring a variable.

Comment: Thanks @Taplar just had to confirm

Comment: They didn't say var and function are the only examples of statements

Comment: @adiga *Declaration Statements:
Such type of statements create variables and functions by using the var and function statements respectively*?

Answer (score 0):

let allows you to declare variables, only difference with var is they are block scoped.

Please go through below for more info :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 0):

I think they are declaration statements as well as initialization statements. If you don't know what initialization statements are, they are the statements which assign a value to a variable for the first time. The statements which assign values to variables which have already been initialized (i.e. they already have a value), are called assignment statements.

Comment: The assumption would be that all `const` would also be initializations, by their very nature.  A `let` though, doesn't have to be initialized immediately.